# Handlebars choose one of two items depending on config value

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

So I want to show one of two kind of photos depending on the value stored in config object, likeso

```
config {
    image_size: 'small'
}
```

then I have an array with differened image sizes

```
images = [{
    'small': small-url,
    'standard': standard-url
}]
```

So far I made my logic in javascript

```
config.image_size === 'small' ?
```

then I map over images and return size I'm interested in.

The question though, can I make that in Handlebars? Ideally I want to change the config with click and load displaying method that will check what size it should be.

Sorry to bother, just wanna see if there's a better way of doing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register a Handlebars helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifCond', function(v1, v2, options) {
  if(v1 === v2) {
    return options.fn(this);
  }
  return options.inverse(this);
});
```

And then use it on your template:

```
{{#ifCond v1 v2}}
    {{v1}} is equal to {{v2}}
{{else}}
    {{v1}} is not equal to {{v2}}
{{/ifCond}}
```